# How to create a public API using the Zend Framework?

Tags: api, zend-framework, web-applications

I have an idea for a web application that would be great if it also had a public API for people to use and interact with. I want people to be able to create their own mobile and desktop applications that interact with the API. Specifically, I want to create an iPhone application that will interact with the API.

I will be building the application with the Zend Framework. I have never created an API, so what do I need to know about creating an API using the Zend Framework? Any tutorials, or advice would be appreciated.

Specifically, I am wondering...If I decide to use XML or JSON as the format, how do I return the data in that format for the client application to use?

**Update:** I realized that I needed to learn what type of API I wanted to implement. [REST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_State_Transfer) and [RPC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_procedure_call) are basically the two different kinds of APIs. [REST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_State_Transfer) is the most simple and common, so I have decided to implement a [RESTful API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_State_Transfer).

**Update:** Here are some resources I've collected so far:

- [Building RESTful Services with Zend Framework - by Matthew Weier O'Phinney](http://weierophinney.net/matthew/archives/228-Building-RESTful-Services-with-Zend-Framework.html#extended)
- [Create RESTful Applications Using The Zend Framework](http://techchorus.net/create-restful-applications-using-zend-framework)
- [Creating a PHP REST API Using the Zend Framework](http://www.chrisdanielson.com/2009/09/02/creating-a-php-rest-api-using-the-zend-framework/)

Comment: I'm not sure whether this is really framework specific or the implementational part of your question should at least be split from the architectural aspects.

As far as the programming is concerned you could easily implement some sort of RESTful API in ZF, but you'll probably rather sooner than later have to make mainly architectural decisions which are not primarily bound to the language or environment you use.

Comment: REST/SOAP...I don't really know the difference, or the first thing about APIs, so maybe you know of some resources to get me started understanding the "language agnostic" architecture?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a good look at Matthew Weier O'Phinney's [presentation](http://www.slideshare.net/weierophinney/architecting-ajax-applications-with-zend-framework) on architecting Ajax apps with Zend Framework, it will probably answer many of your questions.

It's hard to make any specific recommendations, but I would create two modules: one for the web, and one for the API. Both modules would talk to a flexible service layer built on top of your domain models that make it easy to represent your data as both HTML and whatever API format you choose.

Comment: that's a good presentation! mentions most of the things I'm interested in. I wish it were a blog post instead. Not a lot of detailed explanation, which is probably what I am looking for.

Comment: There is! http://weierophinney.net/matthew/archives/227-Exposing-Service-APIs-via-Zend-Framework.html#extended and http://weierophinney.net/matthew/archives/228-Building-RESTful-Services-with-Zend-Framework.html#extended

Answer (score 1):

Try out this book,  http://aarce.com/resources/ebooks/Pro-Zend-Framework-Techniques.pdf . Chapter 9 explain in details how to implement Restful web-service for a Zend Application.

Comment: It *says* that you're building a REST service, but in reality you are not. There is nothing restful about a URL like this: `http://localhost/Api.php?method=search&apiKey=test&keywords=zend`